"... the wee woman that holds my hand and makes my tea." | The wee woman?
A woman with cancer is almost at the end of her life and is thanking everybody who has helped her in some way during her treatment options. She lists each of them and at one point says:

I want to thank the NHS, ........ the surgeons, right down to the wee woman that holds my hand and makes my tea.

BBC-Who knows how long I will be here (see: 00:38-00:43)
"...the wee woman that ..." seemed interesting to me.
Is she referring to a member of staff at a hospital who helped her with toiletting, also made her tea?
Or just an ordinary person small in size (a neighbour, a friend etc) who has helped her, also held her hand and made her tea?

It's probably more figurative than literal - characterizing the tea-lady as unimportant (to the NHS hierarchy), rather than being particularly small in stature.

Now making tea is making peepee?

Certainly the "small" denotation, not the "pee" denotation, whatever the specific connotations she intended.

She's from Glasgow, in Scotland, where people very often say 'wee' for 'small'.  She doesn't seem the type of person to sneeringly call someone a 'little (unimportant) woman', (very much not, in fact), so I'd say that the lady who holds her hand and makes the tea is not very tall.

She wouldn't thank the NHS for a friend or neighbor.

@JackO'Flaherty - considering where the NHS is located, a neighbour?

Or perhaps small in hierarchy, but big in other ways such as kindness and empathy.

How are we supposed to know who makes her tea? That's not an English language question.

@StuartF - I think the OP was uncertain of the meaning of wee!

@KateBunting Presumably because "wee-wee" is a term often used by small children and their parents, referring to peeing.

@Barmar wee is small in Scottish English. There is just no doubt about it at all.

@Barmar - Of course - that goes without saying!

For context, the speaker is Janey Godley who had recently learned her cancer was terminal.
"Wee" is indeed a Scots word meaning small. See Dictionary of Scots Language for most uses:
https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/wee_n1_adj_adv
The use of "wee" here is one of affection, in particular someone who is caring and not a threat.
The intention is likely to highlight the woman's caring nature and that she is someone who has been providing comfort. Furthermore, as remarked in comments,  "wee" emphasises an unimportant person, but worded like that it would read as a little disparaging. A more accurate interpretation is that Janey is highlighting that even the people who would traditionally be perceived as unimportant have earned her gratitude.
See also: Can wee bonnie lass be used for a 2-year-old girl?
